# How do I change the name of the "files" application in Ubuntu unity or gnome

Tags: unity, gnome, default-programs

I'm working on making my Ubuntu machine look like a macOS machine and I would like to change the name of the "Files" executable to "Finder". Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on whether you want this change to apply to your entire Ubuntu installation or only to your user account.

If you want it to only apply to your user account, execute these commands:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
cp /usr/share/applications/nautilus-folder-handler.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
cp /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
```

Then open the files you just copied to `~/.local/share/applications` in a text editor.

If you want the change to apply to your entire Ubuntu installation, open the files you see as the sources in the copy commands above. Note that you need to open these files with root privileges and therefore shouldn't use a graphical text editor.

Example command:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop
```

In the second or third line of these files, it says `Name=Files`. Change it to `Name=Finder` and save. Then log out and log in again.

Comment: Can confirm this works. I just renamed Nautilus as "Nautilus" and Nemo as "Nemo".